# What is the best way to extract data from this response?

Tags: java, regex, string

From a bank I received this response when the client do a transaction, and I need to grep the data from this response. How can I do this..?

The bank response format :

> **{ReceiptNo}** Confirmed. on **{TransactionTime:d}** at **{TransactionTime:t}**  **{Amount}** received from **{1stFor2ndPartyName}**  **{phoneNo}**. Account Number **{AccountNumber}** New Utility balance is **{SecondPartyBalance}**

The strings in the bold will be replaced by actual values, and the format won't be changed.

A sample response :

> 111111 Confirmed. on 2011-11-11 at 14:30 10 received from ABCF
>   457878984545. Account Number 24554455122 New Utility balance is 1000

I'm struggling with it.

Answer (score 2):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+) Confirmed\\. on (.+) at (.+) (.+) received from (.+) (.+)\\. Account Number (.+) New Utility balance is (.+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(anInput);
if (m.matches()) {
    String receiptNo = m.group(1);
    String transactionDate = m.group(2);
    String transactionTime = m.group(3);
    ...
    String secondPartyBalance = m.group(8);

} else {
    throw new RuntimeException("Bank report in wrong format");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'd use a regex -- see
>   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/ and
>   http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html.
>
> String pattern = "/(\d+) Confirmed\. on (\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})
>   at ([\d\:]+) (\d+) ....";
>
> And then use $1, $2, $3.. for your ReceiptNo, etc..

So you'd end up with

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher match = regex.matcher(yourString);
if (!match.matches())
    return some error;

String receiptNumber = match.group(1);
String transactionOn = m.group(2);
....

return above
```

Just like solution 2 below. Do read up on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/ and http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html.

Comment: Seem better solution, will you please explain it more..?

Answer (score 1):

You can use split:
If the format cannot be changed it is faster to use split.

```
String tokens ="111111 Confirmed. on 2011-11-11 at 14:30 10 received from ABCF 457878984545. Account Number 24554455122 New Utility balance is 1000".trim().split(" ");

String receiptNo = tokens[0];
...
```